# ¿Por qué no puedo imprimir los atributos string de un vector de clases?

Tags: c++, array, clase

he creado una clase `Persona` con dos atributos, `edad` y `nombre`, y posteriormente he implementado un vector de personas para intentar imprimir los atributos de los objetos allí introducidos.

Cuando trato de acceder al atributo `edad`, no hay ningún problema y me imprime los valores, pero al intentar acceder al `nombre`, el compilador me dice que hay un error de segmento, así que quería preguntaros por qué ocurre esto y cómo podría solucionarlo. Gracias de antemano.

Código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Persona
{
private:
  string nombre_;
  int edad_;
public:
  Persona(string nombre, int edad);
  inline void setNombre(string nombre) {nombre_=nombre;}
  inline void setEdad(int edad) {edad_=edad;}
  inline string getNombre() {cout<<nombre_;}
  inline int getEdad() {cout<<edad_<<endl;}
};
Persona::Persona(string nombre, int edad)
{
  nombre_=nombre;
  edad_=edad;
}

int main()
{
  Persona m("Mateo",19);
  Persona j("Juan",38);
  Persona l("Lucia",97);
  vector <Persona> vector_personas;
  vector_personas.push_back(m);
  vector_personas.push_back(j);
  vector_personas.push_back(l);
  vector <Persona>::iterator it;
  it=vector_personas.begin();
  while(it!=vector_personas.end())
  {
    it->getNombre();
    it++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Cierto, era por eso, gracias :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Cuando trato de acceder al atributo edad, no hay ningún problema y me imprime los valores

Yo no estaría tan seguro respecto a lo de *"no hay ningún problema"*. Veamos:

```
inline int getEdad() {cout<<edad_<<endl;}
```

Esta función debería retornar un entero... pero no devuelve nada. ¿Y por qué pones el `cout` dentro de `getEdad`?

Lo esperable sería encontrar algo tal que:

```
int getEdad() { return edad_; }

Persona p;
std::cout << p.getEdad();
```

O, mejor aún:

```
int getEdad() const { return edad_; }
```

Ya que este método no debería modificar el estado del objeto. Esto es aplicable también a `getNombre`.

Con estos cambios a mi me compila y funciona perfectamente, como puedes comprobar [aqui](https://wandbox.org/permlink/suNTSx7wTkZ6JS4E)

El error que comentas probablemente se deba a que a la hora de devolver un `string`, el compilador no lo haga del todo bien... ya que no estás retornando nada... No es lo mismo retornar un entero (que es un tipo nativo) a un `string` (que es una clase y tiene su propio destructor)

Comment: Tienes razon, debi haber puesto un return en vez del cout, gracias :)